# Differentiating additive types?

Tags: c++, templates

My first steps in generic programming consists of writing a simple function that accumulates the sum of a vector passed as its argument. The catch is that the function should work only for types with values for which it makes sense to sum.

The code is simple:

```
template <typename T>
T accumulate_sum (const std::vector<T>& v) {
    // check for type and decide whether to sum or return nothing

    T sum = v[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) sum += v[i];
    return sum;
}
```

The question is how to differentiate the additive types?

Comment: If the type is not "additive" you'll get a compiler error. IMHO it's OK as is. Have in mind though that STL has `std::accumulate`.

Comment: Compiler will check possibility to use type T in your template, and give you an error about absence of `operator+`

Comment: next step in generic programming: writing a function that accumulates the generalized sum of an iterator-range `[first, last)`. In other words: study `std::accumulate`

Comment: Thanks guys, so if I've understood write there is some kind of compile time compatibility check between types and operations performed on them?

Comment: You really don't want to silently return nothing when the `+=` is missing for type `T`. So this is quite ok.

Comment: you have a bug: `T sum = v[0];` will crash if your vector is empty. You should initialize with `T sum = 0;` and loop from `i = 0` through `size()` (exclusive). Empty vector should return 0 as sum.

Comment: @TemplateRex Not `T sum = 0;`, `T sum = T();` (or, in C++11, `T sum{};`).

Comment: @Angew assuming `T` is default-constructible! (Although if it isn't then it's unclear what this function should return for an empty vector, it'd probably have to throw or return `optional<T>`). Another point is that in the most general case, `T{} + a + b` may differ from `a + b`.

Comment: @M.M by doing `T sum = v[0]` I was actually trying to avoid defining _additive identity_. Because I didn't know what was a better solution to return: _a default value_ or _additive identity_, to indicate no sum.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis yep; you'll need to first decide what behaviour you want to happen for an empty vector, and then the code will follow naturally from that choice

Comment: "trying to avoid defining additive identity". Add another argument (sum's initial value) to the function. Supply a reasonable default value like `T()`. This way you don't assume anything about properties of your type.

Comment: As an aside, I would write as `template <typename T, class U>
T accumulate_sum (const U& v, T initial = T()) { for (const auto& el : v) initial += el; return initial; }`.  That way you can iterate over any enumerable type.  (Note that I pass `initial` by value so I can use it to accumulate in.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template function imposes an **implicit interface** on its template parameters. If there is no `operator+=` for your type `T`, then you will get a compiler error.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T accumulate_sum (const std::vector<T>& v) {
    // check for type and decide whether to sum or return nothing

    T sum = v[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) sum += v[i];
    return sum;
} 

struct Test {}; // not additive

int main()
{
    std::vector<Test> v { Test{}, Test{} };
    accumulate_sum(v);
}
```

This will give the following error message ([**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f77fbc4a2e283475))

> ```
> main.cpp:10:47: error: no viable overloaded '+='
>     for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) sum += v[i];
>                                           ~~~ ^  ~~~~
> main.cpp:19:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'accumulate_sum<Test>' requested here
>     accumulate_sum(v);
>     ^
>
> 1 error generated.
> ```

With the Concepts Technical Specification, you can add syntactic constraits and get better error messages. You could do this with `static_assert` as well.

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
using add_inc_t = decltype(std::declval<T&>() += std::declval<T>());

template<class T>
constexpr auto is_additive_v = std::experimental::is_detected_v<add_inc_t, T>;

template <typename T>
T accumulate_sum (const std::vector<T>& v) {
    static_assert(is_additive_v<T>, "the type T needs to be additive by providing operator+");

    // as before
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jm4ntBpLp2i3iBLA) using gcc 6.0 SVN trunk (not yet released).

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! Is adding `assert(v.size())` before initializing the local variable `sum` a good idea ?

Comment: no, you need to zero-initalize `sum` and loop from `i = 0; i < size()`

Comment: I appreciate the great explanation and example. I guess the general solution should contain an additional argument, defaulted to numerical addition `+`, that handles the objects with strange laws for summation.